# Magento 1.4 installation

Tags: magento-1.4

[image]

I have installed Magento version 1.4.While doing installation i got attached image error

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this could be your .htaccess-file, it could be an apache redirect, a virtual host issue, a lot of possibilities, but the most likely one, is that Magento doesn't like ip-addresses.

Add something like this in your host file (locations differ for linux, osx and windows):

```
182.71.235.230    localhost.com
```

Than try to run it again, but by calling `http://localhost.com/billbeautyshop/`.